# how to parse the json result using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json, jquery-append

I have the following ajax call to make a call to webservice and retreive back the json data

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "Test.asmx/GetImages",
                success: function (msg) {
                    //var data = JSON.parse(msg); 
                    alert(msg.d);
                   $.each(msg.results, function (i, tweet) {
                        alert(msg.d);
                        $("#imagelist").append('<p><img src="' + tweet + '" />' + tweet + '</p>');
                    });
                }
            });
 });
```

I have following json result obtained from the ajax call, I am finding difficult to append the img source .

```
{"d":"[\r\n  {\r\n    \"imagepath\": \"images/01.jpg\"\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"imagepath\": \"images/02.jpg\"\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"imagepath\": \"images/03.jpg\"\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"imagepath\": \"images/04.jpg\"\r\n  }\r\n]"}
```

Comment: Following article clearly explains the solution http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/96/Handling-JSON-Arrays-returned-from-ASP.NET-Web-Services-with-jQuery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just specify `dataType: 'json'` and jquery will do that automatically for you

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks for the reply , how to individually extract images/01.jpg,images/02.jpg................  , from the result data from $.each function

Comment: @mahesh: iterate over `msg.d`

Comment: Its behaving crazy , when i execute saying  $.each({ "d": "[\r\n  {\r\n    \"imagepath\": \"images/01.jpg\"\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"imagepath\": \"images/04.jpg\"\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"imagepath\": \"images/04.jpg\"\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"imagepath\": \"images/04.jpg\"\r\n  }\r\n]" }, function (k, v) {
            alert("Value: " + v);
        });

Comment: alert is trig erring only once since their are four imagepath , i expect it to trigger four times , is their any thing wrong with the syntax.

Comment: @mahesh: it's triggered once because the object you passed has **only one property** with name `d`. And you need to pass array instead

Comment: ya i am getting what you are trying to explain, should i change the json result which i am getting back from the webservice, you mean to say that should be a array

Comment: @mahesh: you can just traverse over `msg.d` which is an array

Comment: $.each(msg.d, function (i, tweet) { alert(tweet); }); i have changed the syntax as above

Comment: @mahesh: no, traverse over `msg.d`, not over `msg.d.imagepath` (it is the 3rd time :-S)

Comment: I assume the json result is fine , i have to make some minor changes in parsing the result i guess ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply , i got it working , it was clearly explained in this article http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/96/Handling-JSON-Arrays-returned-from-ASP.NET-Web-Services-with-jQuery